# How to register Tomcat server in Netbeans 8.0.15

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, web-applications, tomcat8

I have just installed Netbeans 8.0.2 bundle including Java EE and Tomcat 8.0.15.
The server is working fine in services tab.
But whenever I try to make new Java EE project, following error shows up

No servers are registered in the IDE. To register a server, click the "Add..." button.

It shows the same error even if I add the server again.
How to resolve this issue
I am using Windows7

Comment: Let's follow what Netbeans notice: `To register a server, click the "Add..." button.`

Answer (score 0):

You will add server like this:
[image]

See [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9o-Zq-hMzuM). With Netbeans 8 will like Netbean 7.x, in this case.